# Spectrum of a unitary

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I have a unitary element $v$ in $C(S^{1}, \mathbb{C})$ with full spectrum (the whole circle). Is it possible to construct another unitary $u$ in $C(S^{1}, \mathbb{C})$ out of $v$ such that the spectrum of $u$ is not full (i.e. a unitary with smaller range)?

Comment: What about $u=v^*v=1$?

Comment: The question is unclear.  What does "construct ... out of $v$" mean?  There is a comment on an answer: "Yes, the unitary must satisfy specific relations. I can't easily explain the relations unless I type a long theorem here."  If you cannot tell us what relations answers are supposed to satisfy, how is it possible to answer?  Why not type the long theorem here?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a surjective continuous map $v:S^1\to S^1$ and would like to construct a non-surjective continuous map $u:S^1\to S^1$ out of it. One way to do so is to let $u=f\circ v$ where $f:S^1\to S^1$ is continuous and not surjective. For example, $f(x+iy)=x+i|y|$ and $f(x+iy)=|x|+iy$ both do the job. So does a constant $f$, of course.

If you'd like to have some specific relation between $u$ and $v$, you should clarify the equation.

Comment: Yes, the unitary must satisfy specific relations. I can't easily explain the relations unless I type a long theorem here. Thank you for your answers though.